# Laravel migration. I cannot add two foreign key referenced to same table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

```
Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('year');
        $table->integer('groups_number');

        $table->primary(['year','groups_number']);

    });

    Schema::create('student_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('student_groups_year');
        $table->integer('student_groups_number');

        $table->primary(['student_groups_year', 'student_groups_number']);

    });
```

---

```
Schema::table('student_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->foreign('student_groups_year')
        ->references('year')->on('groups');

        $table->foreign('student_groups_number')
        ->references('groups_number')->on('groups');
    });
```

These are two diffrent files. I make the table in one file and the foreign keys in the other. The problem is when I make the second foreign key. When I only make one foreign key it works just fine, but when I make the second it get error. Anyway know why I can't make two foreign keys referenced to the same table? This is the error message I get.

```
In Connection.php line 664:
```

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `bpo`.`#sql-26ec_995` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `student_groups` add constraint `student_grou
  ps_student_groups_number_foreign` foreign key (`student_groups_number`) references `groups` (`groups_number`))

In Connection.php line 458:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `bpo`.`#sql-26ec_995` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I found the answer!! Couldn't find this anywhere and it was so simple! You have to put it in same foreign key code.

```
$table->foreign(['student_groups_number','student_groups_year'])
            ->references(['group_number','year'])->on('groups');
```

Comment: Add code/text not images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer!! Couldn't find this anywhere and it was so simple! You have to put it in same foreign key code.

```
$table->foreign(['student_groups_number','student_groups_year'])
        ->references(['group_number','year'])->on('groups');
```

Answer (score 0):

change your foreign keys to an unsigned integer you can do this like

```
        $table->integer('student_groups_number')->unsigned();
```

and make sure dont use `varchar` type as foreign key.

```
    $table->integer('student_groups_year')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('student_groups_number')->unsigned();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's the "student_groups_ar" who is the problem. I tried putting unsigned on it and changed it to int but still the same error:

Comment: Migration table created successfully.

In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `bpo`.`#sql-26ec_4c` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `student_groups` add constraint `student_group
  s_student_groups_ar_foreign` foreign key (`student_groups_ar`) references `groups` (`ar`))


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `bpo`.`#sql-26ec_4c` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: @StianEriksen I have updated the answer you have to create every foriegn key colum to unsigned integer else it is not going to work

Comment: Hi, I tried changing it to unsigned, but the problem then was it turned the foreign key to int 10, but the primary was int 11. So it didn't let me connect them. But it did work fine after the fix I found, even without unsigned :)